# What is the full form of “A.T.O.M.”?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, legends-of-tomorrow

What is the full form of “A.T.O.M.” used in DC’s *Legends of Tomorrow* for the A.T.O.M. suit worn by Ray Palmer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Advanced Technology Operating Mechanism.

From the companion show, *Arrow*:

> RAY PALMER: But I’m kind of partial to A.T.O.M. Advanced Technology Operating
> Mechanism.
>
> <sub>*Arrow*, “The Climb”</sub>

Yes, this does seem a bit sillier than merely naming it after the physics concept, but then again, people love funny names like this, [even scientists.](http://www.businessinsider.com/15-fantastic-scientific-acronyms-2014-1)

Comment: That... Is not impressive.